# Google translate character limit in a single POST

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-translate

I have seen in unofficial comments that there is a 5000 character limit. In a single request I am sending an **array** of strings to be translated which could exceed this limit in total. It's also unclear if this limit applies to a single item in the array, or the total.

I need to know if I have to modify my logic to batch up these requests if there is a limit imposed but I couldn't find relevant information in the docs, including under https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas

Answer (score 1):

The 5000 character limit refers to all characters in the requests. It's briefly mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq).

It's a performance limit, not an artificial one, so I don't think stacking them in arrays who make it any better.

Comment: Thanks, it's still a bit confusing as it says it's the recommended limit. The array isn't artificial, it's a key-value store of translations for software e.g. `"nav-back": "Go back"`. Would be good to get a definite response, since I have to get all these values translated there is no performance gain from splitting up into multiple requests, they would all have to be waited on anyway before the final result